# How can i wait for a frame to perform an action before the code execute the next line?

Tags: java

I want to initialize a Graphical User Interface (GUI) for the user to input a form. After this is accomplished i want to open a new GUI, but as soon as the first GUI pops-up the next one is initialized to.

Is there any way to solve this without using waits and notifies?

here is an example of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUIForm(); 
    // wait until the user inputs the complete form
    new GUIWelcome();

}
```

It is really simple I woild like to keep it that way.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use some event handling. One possible solution is to add a button to the first Frame that the user must click before continuing to the next Frame

Comment: You could use a Semaphore in the constructors of FUIFrom and GUIWelcome

Comment: Moral dialogs and CardLayout come to mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an Interface OnActionListener

```
public interface OnActionListener {
    public void onAction();
}
```

Add these code in GUIForm class

```
private OnActionListener listener;
private JButton action;

public GUIForm(OnActionListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
    action = new JButton("Action");
    action.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            GUIForm.this.listener.onAction();
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can achieve that

```
new GUIForm(new OnActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAction() {
            new GUIWelcome();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort pub/sub mechanism. This in a nutshell is what you need:

```
public class PubSub {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("GUIForm");
    frame1.setSize(640, 480);
    JButton button = new JButton("User Input");

    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Welcome");
    frame2.setSize(320, 240);

    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            button.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            button.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            frame2.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.add(button);
    frame1.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

This version uses JFrame's listeners, but you could implement your on callback mechanism to accomplish the same